# Moving a rectangle (or any kivy graphic) between 2 points

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to have a rectangle move between 2 points, so when the rectangle reaches point A it then moves back to point B. I am able to create a rectangle and animate the rectangle to move to a point but I'm unsure how I set up an 'if statement' to read the rectangles position and move it back.

```
def animate_the_button(self, *kwargs):
    self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(75,10), size=(10,50))
    self.canvas.add(self.rect)
    anim = Animation(pos=(75,700))
    anim.start(self.rect)
```

Comment: The animation has an `on_complete` event that you can bind to to do something when the animation finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a function or method when an animation completes, use `bind()` with `on_complete`:

```
anim.bind(on_complete=self.animate_way_back)
```

Where `animate_way_back()` would be a method that sends the rectangle on its way back. See the documentation on [Animation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.animation.html).

But since you seem to want it to keep bouncing back and forth, a repeating sequence of animations seems a better fit:

```
anim = Animation(pos=(75,700)) + Animation(pos=(75,10))
anim.repeat = True
anim.start(self.rect)
```